# opengl not showing output from renderFunction

Tags: c, opengl, glut, bresenham, opengl-compat

I was implementing this dda algorithm using opengl. However, for some reason, it doesn't plot the second line. I tried putting printf at every line, which shows that it IS executing. However, there is no output in my window

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int choice = 0;

void DDA(x0, y0, x1, y1)
const x0, y0, x1, y1;
{
    glOrtho(-500, 500, -500, 500, -1, 1);
    float dx = x1 - x0;
    float dy = y1 - y0;
    int steps = abs(dx) > abs(dy) ? abs(dx) : abs(dy);
    float xInc = (float)steps/dx;
    float yInc = (float)steps/dy;
    int x = x0, y = y0;
    for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glColor3f(1.0, 3.0, 2.0);
            glVertex2i(x, y);
            x += xInc;
            y += yInc;
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }
}

void Bresenham(x0, y0, x1, y1)
const x0, y0, x1, y1;
{
    glOrtho(-500, 500, -500, 500, -1, 1);
    int x = x0;
    int y = y0;
    int dx = x1 - x0;
    int dy = y1 - y0;
    int p = 2*dy-dx;
    int m = dy / dx;
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); {
        glColor3f(2.0, 3.0, 5.0);
        while(x != x1) {
            if(m < 1) {
                glVertex2i(x, y);
                x++;
                if(p >= 0) {
                    p += 2*(dy - dx);
                    y++;
                }
                else {
                    p += 2*dy;
                }
            }
            else {
                glVertex2i(x, y);
                y++;
                if(p >= 0) {
                    p += 2*(dx - dy);
                    x++;
                }
                else {
                    p += 2*dx;
                }
            }
        }
        glVertex2i(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void circle(x0, y0, r)
const x0, y0, r;
{

}

void renderDDA(void) {
    DDA(0, 0, 300, 400);
    DDA(0, 0, 200, 200);
}

void renderBresenham(void) {
    Bresenham(0, 0, 300, 100);
    Bresenham(0, 0, 500, 0);
}

void renderCircle(void) {

}

main(argc, argv)
char** argv;
{
redo:   
    printf("ENTER YOUR CHOICE: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1920, 1680);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[1]);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    switch (choice) {
        case 0:
            glutDisplayFunc(renderDDA);
            break;
        case 1:
            glutDisplayFunc(renderBresenham);
            break;
        case 2:
            glutDisplayFunc(renderCircle);
            break;
        default:
            printf("NO SUCH CHOICE!!");
            goto redo;
    }
    glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

I also tried swapping the lines. Then it draws only the upper line. it does execute the second call however.

Comment: my algorithms work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) does not set an orthographic projection, it defines an orthographic projection matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the orthographic projection matrix.

You've to set the identity matrix before calling `glOrtho`:

```cpp
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-500, 500, -500, 500, -1, 1);
```

Further there is an issue in the algorithm. The type of `x` and `y` has to be `float`. If you would trunc the result to `int`, then it is only possible to draw lines with angles that are aligned to multiples of 45 degreess, because `x` and `y` change exactly by 0 or 1 at each step:

```cpp
float x = x0, y = y0;
for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glColor3f(1.0, 3.0, 2.0);
        glVertex2i((int)(x+0.5f), (int)(y+0.5f));
        x += xInc;
        y += yInc;
    glEnd();
}
```

Note, changing the type from `int` to `float` causes that `x` and `y` are tracked with full precision. `glVertex2i((int)(x+0.5f), (int)(y+0.5f))` ensures that coordinates (`x`, `y`) are rounded to the integral position when the point is draw.

---

I recommend to move the setting of the projection matrix from and `glFlush` from `DDA` respectively `Bresenham` to `renderDDA` respectively `renderBresenham`:

```cpp
void DDA(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1)
{
    float dx = x1 - x0;
    float dy = y1 - y0;
    int steps = abs(dx) > abs(dy) ? abs(dx) : abs(dy);
    float xInc = (float)steps/dx;
    float yInc = (float)steps/dy;
    float x = x0, y = y0;
    for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glColor3f(1.0, 3.0, 2.0);
            glVertex2i((int)(x+0.5f), (int)(y+0.5f));
            x += xInc;
            y += yInc;
        glEnd();
    }
}

void Bresenham(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1)
{
    int x = x0;
    int y = y0;
    int dx = x1 - x0;
    int dy = y1 - y0;
    int p = 2*dy-dx;
    int m = dy / dx;
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); {
        glColor3f(2.0, 3.0, 5.0);
        while(x != x1) {
            if(m < 1) {
                glVertex2i(x, y);
                x++;
                if(p >= 0) {
                    p += 2*(dy - dx);
                    y++;
                }
                else {
                    p += 2*dy;
                }
            }
            else {
                glVertex2i(x, y);
                y++;
                if(p >= 0) {
                    p += 2*(dx - dy);
                    x++;
                }
                else {
                    p += 2*dx;
                }
            }
        }
        glVertex2i(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void renderDDA(void) {
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-500, 500, -500, 500, -1, 1);
    DDA(0, 0, 300, 400);
    DDA(0, 0, 200, 200);
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void renderBresenham(void) {
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-500, 500, -500, 500, -1, 1);
    Bresenham(0, 0, 300, 100);
    Bresenham(0, 0, 500, 0);
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work :(. And isn't that exactly what's happening here? I mean the renderFunction which is after loadIdentity is executing glOrtho.

Comment: @kesarling Patience, ther is more than 1 issue.

Comment: Oh sorry. I also tried making x and y float. It is now drawing the line dotted.

Comment: and is still drawing only one line

Comment: @kesarling I've 2 lines.

Comment: Nice. after the new editing in renderFunction, I got two lines. Why did mine did not work?

Comment: @kesarling Because x and y are increments by either -1, 0 or 1, this allows only lines which are aligned to in 45 degrees.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192381/discussion-between-kesarling-and-rabbid76).

Comment: What I meant was how does changing those two particular lines to be included in the renderFuntions work?

Comment: @kesarling Changing the type from `int` to `float` causes that  `x` and `y` are tracked with full precision. `glVertex2i((int)(x+0.5f), (int)(y+0.5f))` ensures that coordinates `x` and `y` are rounded to the integral position.